# Failed to connect to local host

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to the Android App Development. I am making a demo Android app in Android studio(Kotlin). My app is basically is a server app. I am using retrofit as a library and node.js as a backend development and I am not using any database, instead of Database, I am using JSON(gson retrofit converter). So, There is a recyclerview in which, I want to fetch data, but when, I run my app in my android phone. It shows java.net socket Timeout Exception, fail to connect. At, First, I have changed my 127.0.0.1:9000 to 10.0.2.2:9000 port, but nothing happened. It showing the same thing. And I am using windows pc. I will provide my .js file and my front code. Thank you in advance.

```js
//my node.js codes

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

//Arbitrary ID manager since we don't use a database
var index = 5;

// Initializing Destinations Array.. It will behave like a dummy database 
var destinations = [{
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan quis justo quis hendrerit. Curabitur a ante neque. Fusce nec mauris sodales, auctor sem at, luctus eros. Praesent aliquam nibh neque. Duis ut suscipit justo, id consectetur orci. Curabitur ultricies nunc eu enim dignissim, sed laoreet odio blandit.",
    "country" : "India"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan quis justo quis hendrerit. Curabitur a ante neque. Fusce nec mauris sodales, auctor sem at, luctus eros. Praesent aliquam nibh neque. Duis ut suscipit justo, id consectetur orci. Curabitur ultricies nunc eu enim dignissim, sed laoreet odio blandit.",
    "country" : "Australia"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "city": "Washington DC",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan quis justo quis hendrerit. Curabitur a ante neque. Fusce nec mauris sodales, auctor sem at, luctus eros. Praesent aliquam nibh neque. Duis ut suscipit justo, id consectetur orci. Curabitur ultricies nunc eu enim dignissim, sed laoreet odio blandit.",
    "country" : "USA"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "city": "New Delhi",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan quis justo quis hendrerit. Curabitur a ante neque. Fusce nec mauris sodales, auctor sem at, luctus eros. Praesent aliquam nibh neque. Duis ut suscipit justo, id consectetur orci. Curabitur ultricies nunc eu enim dignissim, sed laoreet odio blandit.",
    "country" : "India"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan quis justo quis hendrerit. Curabitur a ante neque. Fusce nec mauris sodales, auctor sem at, luctus eros. Praesent aliquam nibh neque. Duis ut suscipit justo, id consectetur orci. Curabitur ultricies nunc eu enim dignissim, sed laoreet odio blandit.",
    "country" : "Japan"
}]

// A promo message to user 
var message = "Black Friday! Get 50% cachback on saving your first spot.";

app.get('/messages', function (req, res) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(message));
})

// Get the list of destinations, convert it to JSON and send it back to client 
app.get('/destination', function (req, res) {
    var count = req.query.count != undefined ? req.query.count : req.query.count = 100;
    if(req.query.country){
        var countrySpots = destinations.filter(function(destination) {
            return destination.country == req.query.country
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify(countrySpots.slice(0, count)));
    }
    
    res.end(JSON.stringify(destinations.slice(0, count)));
})

// Get one particular Destination using ID 
app.get('/destination/:id', function (req, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
        if(destinations[i].id == req.params.id){
            res.end(JSON.stringify(destinations[i]));
        }
    }
})

// Create a new Destination and add it to existing Destinations list 
app.post('/destination', function (req, res) {
    var newDestination = {
        "city": req.body.city,
        "description": req.body.description,
        "country" : req.body.country,
        "id": index + 1
    }

    index++;

    destinations.push(newDestination);
    res.status(201).end(JSON.stringify(newDestination));
})

// Update a Destination 
app.put('/destination/:id', function (req, res) {
    var destination;
    for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
        if(destinations[i].id == req.params.id){
            destinations[i].city = req.body.city;
            destinations[i].country = req.body.country;
            destinations[i].description = req.body.description;
            destination = destinations[i];
        }
    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(destination));
})

// Delete a Destination 
app.delete('/destination/:id', function (req, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
        if(destinations[i].id == req.params.id){
            destinations.splice(i, 1);
            res.status(204).end(JSON.stringify(destinations[i]));
        }
    }
});

// Home Page 
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome! You are all set to go!'))

// Configure server 
var server = app.listen(9000, '127.0.0.1', function (req, res) {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log(`Server running at http://${host}:${port}/`);
})
```

DestinationListActivity

```
class DestinationListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_destiny_list)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar.title = title

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@DestinationListActivity, DestinationCreateActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    loadDestinations()
}

private fun loadDestinations() {

    // To be replaced by retrofit code
    //  destiny_recycler_view.adapter = DestinationAdapter(SampleData.DESTINATIONS)

    val destination = ServiceBuilder.buildService(DestinationService::class.java)

    val requestCall = destination.getDestinationList()

    requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Destination>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Destination>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@DestinationListActivity , "Error Occures" + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Destination>>, response: Response<List<Destination>>) {
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                val destinationList = response.body()!!
                destiny_recycler_view.adapter = DestinationAdapter(destinationList)
            } else if(response.code() == 401) {
                Toast.makeText(this@DestinationListActivity, "Your session is over plz login again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this@DestinationListActivity, "Failed to receive items", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

//ServiceBuilder class

```
object ServiceBuilder {

// Before release, change this URL to your live server URL such as "https://smartherd.com/"
private const val URL = "http://47.247.190.247:9000/"

// Create OkHttp Client
private val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                  .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                  .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS)

// Create Retrofit Builder
private val builder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttp.build())

// Create Retrofit Instance
private val retrofit = builder.build()

fun <T> buildService(serviceType: Class<T>): T {
    return retrofit.create(serviceType)
}
```

}

//Interface class

```
interface DestinationService {

@GET("destination")
fun getDestinationList(): Call<List<Destination>>
```

}

[It is a photo of my android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJXzS.jpg)

Comment: I am using retrofit2 and I have also shared my android app screenshot

Comment: What android emulator are you using?

Comment: is that your localhost ip and is it work on postman ?

Comment: I am not using an emulator, my laptop is running on i3, due to which it is very slow to run, an emulator. I have run my app on my android phone. I have provided a screenshot of it.

Comment: yes, it's my localhost IP and yes it is work on postman

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. My localhost is not connected with my android phone, that's why its showing port error. So, to connect my android phone to localhost. I actually public my localhost using "ngrok". Then, my data is loading on my android phone. Thank you.